# Htaccess Block all php file in certain directories

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to secure my wordpress site through htaccess - By blocking php files from folders.

**Example:**

1. Deny all php files in wp-content
2. Allow php files in in wp-admin and wp-includes
3. On home directory, allow index.php and allow all files with wp and deny all.

So Far:

Deny wp-config.php

```
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Run only certain files (but i cant get directory to work on this level)

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match directories using `Files` directive.

Have these 2 rules as your very first rules in main WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/.+?\.php - [NC,F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|wp.+?)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?[^./]+\.php - [NC,F]
```

Don't forget to remove all the `Files` blocks.

Comment: Would u recommend i do this at the httpd.conf

Comment: If you already have a WO .htaccess and might as well do it there. Alternatively you can do this in `httpd.conf` (see updated rules that will work in both places)

Comment: I want to be able to redirect it to the homepage if file is opened, anyway of doing that? code so far `RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/.+?\.php$ / [NC,F]` (want to be able to do it dynamically without entering in the url

Comment: You can do: `RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/.+?\.php / [NC,L,R=302]` for that.

Comment: this answer doesn't helped me at all

Comment: Post a new question with all the details and you will get good answers